# syntax error missing operator in query expression c# using access as database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm getting syntax error in all my inputs into the textboxes.

In my database all the requirement is string other than the ID which is an autonumber, I try to search for possible answer but all didn't work or maybe I just missed some answer

Here is the error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''hasdasd'password
>   = 'h'account_Type='Manager'Name='h'Middle_Name='h'Surname'h'address'h'BirthDate='3/17/1999'Mobile_Number'65465''.

Code:

```
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime bdate = DateTime.Parse(birthdate.Value.ToShortDateString());
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString());

    int age = currentDate.Year - bdate.Year;
    String id = emp_view.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + String.Empty;
    int id1 = Int32.Parse(id);

    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\dbms\jollibee.accdb";
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "update Employee_Details set username = '" + username.Text +
                                                            "'password = '" + password.Text +
                                                            "'account_Type='" + accountType.Text +
                                                            "'Name='" + name.Text +
                                                            "'Middle_Name='" + middlename.Text +
                                                            "'Surname'" + surname.Text +
                                                            "'address'" + address.Text +
                                                            "'BirthDate='" + birthdate.Value.ToShortDateString() +
                                                            "'Mobile_Number'" + mobilenumber.Text +
                                                            "'where ID = '" + id1 + "'";

        if (username.Text.Equals("") ||
            username.Text.Equals("") ||
            password.Text.Equals("") ||
            middlename.Text.Equals("") ||
            surname.Text.Equals("") ||
            address.Text.Equals("") ||
            accountType.Text.Equals("") ||
            mobilenumber.Text.Equals("")
           )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill all fields.");
            con.Close();
        }
        else if (age < 18)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are not allowed to work because you are under age..");
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(username.Text + "is now updated on database.");
            list();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would *start* by fixing your SQL to use parameters. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and certainly won't do the right thing if a user enters a name with an apostrophe. Using parameters will *also* make the SQL clearer, and it'll make it obvious where the problem is. (Print out the SQL you're currently using and I think it will be pretty clear that it's not what you want it to be.)

Comment: you need   comma (,) between fields

Comment: @DaisyShipton vulnerabilities are ok since it is only a school project.

Comment: Surely the point of a school project is to learn about the technologies you're dealing with - and one of the *most important* things to learn about when writing SQL is how to avoid SQL injection attacks. Using parameterized SQL will help *every aspect* of your code, including making it obvious where your current (multiple) problems are. Why resist that?

Comment: you are correct, I though that is ok that's why I said that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing code, there are issues like.

1- Column in update are not separated by ","

2- All string are not separated using quotes `''`

You should always avoid writing queries inline by concatenation of string. This will make you code vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.

To read more about **SQL Injections** check [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Change your code like following using command parameters.

```
cmd.CommandText = "update Employee_Details set [username] = @un, [password] = @pw, [account_Type]= @at, [Name] = @nm, [Middle_Name]= @mn, [Surname]= @sn, [address]= @add, [BirthDate] = @bd, [Mobile_Number] = @mn WHERE [Id]=@id";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@un", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = username.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pw", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = password.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@at", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = accountType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nm", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mn", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = middlename.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sn", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = surname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@add", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = address.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bd", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(birthdate.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mn", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mobilenumber.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = id1;
```

**Note:** You need to correct the datatype based on your table structure as it is now known to me.

Comment: i got a new error `syntax error in update statement`

Comment: Update syntax is correct, anyway there are few keywords, i have updated the command string, you can give a try

Answer (score 0):

Your *completely malformed* SQL should look like:

```
       cmd.CommandText = "update Employee_Details set " +
                         "username = '" + username.Text + "',"+
                         "[password] = '" + password.Text + "'," +
                         "account_Type = '" + accountType.Text + "'," +
                         "[Name] = '" + name.Text + "'," +
                         "Middle_Name = '" + middlename.Text + "'," +
                         "Surname = '" + surname.Text + "'," +
                         "address = '" + address.Text + "'," +
                         "BirthDate = #" + birthdate.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/dd") + "#," +
                         "Mobile_Number = '" + mobilenumber.Text + "' " +
                         "where ID = " + id1 + "";
```

That said, DO use parameters as already explained. Much easier and safer.